# How to count a number of links with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I cant show the number of links in the textarea.. I use this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    var url = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

    $("#textarea").on("keyup", function( e ) {
        var urls, output = "";
        if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 32 && e.keyCode !== 46 ) {
            // Return is backspace, tab, enter, space or delete was not pressed.
            return;
        }

        while ((urls = url.exec(this.value)) !== null) {
            output += urls[0] + ", ";
        }
        $("#result").html("URLS: " + output.substring(0, output.length - 2));
    });
});
</script>

<textarea id="textarea" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

But this show the name of urls for example:

Insert in textarea:

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.amazon.com
```

Show:

```
URLS: https://www.google.com, https://www.amazon.com
```

But I need show:

```
URLS: 2
```

I try with:

```
$("#result").html("URLS: " + output.length);
```

But get the number of letters of the URLS.

Anyone can help me? thx so much

Comment: diana, are you looking for the string length of all URLs combined or for the number of URLs? Please specify, thanks.

Comment: url.exec(this.value).length should give you the number

Comment: if you need to see how many links, why divide them by `,` ? just use an array and push each of your links inside that array and then use `length`. You use `length` on a string which will return the nr of chars in that string.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `output` an array instead of a string, you can use the `length` property:

`var output = [];`

and

`while ((urls = url.exec(this.value)) !== null) {
    output.push( urls[0] );
 }`

and

`$("#result").html("URLS: " + output.length );`

```js
"use strict";
var url = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

document.querySelector( 'textarea' ).addEventListener( 'keyup', function( e ) {
  var urls;
  var output = [];
  if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 32 && e.keyCode !== 46 ) {
            // Return is backspace, tab, enter, space or delete was not pressed.
            return;
        }

  while ((urls = url.exec(this.value)) !== null) {
    output.push( urls[ 0 ] );
  }
  document.querySelector( '#result' ).innerHTML = "URLS: " + output.length;
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector( '#result' )` why not use `documentGetElementById` if you select the element by it's ID which is unique.

Comment: @MihaiT Because the speed difference is so minimal that you won't notice it. If you go for getElementById, that also means you have to go for getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName. And still use querySelector for every selector that those 3 won't find. So I prefer to always use querySelector and querySelectorAll for everything so my code stays consistent. 2 different selector functions vs 5 different ones.

Comment: In which case, just stick with `$("#...` as OP is already using jquery.

Comment: I could, but I like to answer in pure JS unless the OP specifically asks for a JQuery ( or toher library ) version so my answers don't become obsolete once JQuery becomes extinct. It's also a nice way to show collegues how to do those things without JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a variable i, initialize it with zero outside of loop. and for every iteration of loop increase i with 1.

[Go here for solution demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU4TPYVI8R2N)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
var url = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

$("#textarea").on("keyup", function( e ) {
    var urls, output = "";
    if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 32 && e.keyCode !== 46 ) {
        // Return is backspace, tab, enter, space or delete was not pressed.
        return;
    }

    while ((urls = url.exec(this.value)) !== null) {
        output += urls[0] + ", ";
    }
    $("#result").html("URLS: " + output.substring(0, output.length - 2));
});
```

});

To:

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
var url = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gmi;

$("#textarea").on("keyup", function( e ) {
    var urls, output = "";
    if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 32 && e.keyCode !== 46 ) {
        // Return is backspace, tab, enter, space or delete was not pressed.
        return;
    }

  var urls = this.value.match(url);

  $("#result").html(urls.length);
});
```

});

https://codepen.io/jthomas077/pen/gjZbPe

Note: You can still iterate over the matches if you need too.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  Rather than just "change your code", please add a small description, eg "Using `this.value.match(url)` in place of `url.exec` will return an array which can be manipulated as required".